# ScrollView doesn't scroll when added a subview to a view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have a `ViewController1` which has a `ScrollView`. In that `Scrollview`, I am adding another `ViewController2`. Everything is working fine as expected. I could able to scroll the view. Here in this `ViewController2`, I am trying to add subview another view with separate view class initialising frame from `ViewController2`. When I add this, everything is visible and working fine but the view doesn't allow the scrollview to scroll.

The hierarchy is like this

UIViewController1(Root) --> UIScrollView

UIScrollView's subview --> UIViewController2

UIViewController2's subview --> UIView(separate class frame sent from UIViewController2)

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are setting frames properly? Make sure that nothing is overlapping that scrollView, you can also check whether a `contentSize` of that `scrollView` requires scrolling. Those are the things I would start looking at your problem's description.

With overlapping layers you can check it on simulator (`Debug` option and then set `Color Blended Layers`)

Comment: The view, I am adding has frame 0,0,320,320. I am able to scroll if I touch above 320. i.e. below that view.

Comment: Another thing that came up to my mind - are you sure you haven't added anything over scroll (for example something to the root's view)?

Comment: Nope. RootViewController just have the scrollView in which second half with two buttons and labels are added. first half with the viewcontroller2 which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: if only you could past code then it would be easier to figure out what is wrong

Comment: found out the issue. It was pan gesture recognizer over riding scrollview's scroll. I need to change my logic to replace gesture recognizer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It was hard to guess according to info you provided but I'm happy that you have solved it :)